# Tkinter: Move a thousand points randomly

Tags: python, random, tkinter, move

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so I'm sorry if it isnt perfect of clear. So, I need help with my program for my CompSci class.

Here are the instructions:

Initialize 1000 points at the center of your window.

- At each time step repeat 1000 times...

  - Flip a four-sided coin, then move a point up or down or left or
    right. 
    -The idea is to do this independently for each of the 1000
    points. So, one point's movement does not aect any other point's
    movement.
  - Draw a "dot" or a 1 x 1 rectangle at each point's current
    location.
  - Attach three screen shots showing early, middle, and late
    distributions.

I have pasted below what I've got so far:

The problem with this code is: It wont show the points "moving". My instructor want it to be like a animation. Because there is a 1000 points and they are moving a thousand times, the delay between the different "frames" have to very short.

If anyone can help me do this, I would be very thankful.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from random import randint


d=0
t=0
v=1000

x = []
y = []
for i in range(1000):
    x.append(300)
    y.append(300)





root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg="white")#creates the canvas

for l in range(v):
    for k in range(t):
        for i in range(len(x)):
            x[i] += randint(-2,2)
            y[i] += randint(-2,2)



    for i in range(1000):
        canvas.create_rectangle(x[i],y[i],x[i],y[i])
    if l < 999:
        for i in range(1000):
            canvas.create_rectangle(x[i],y[i],x[i],y[i], outline='white')

    t+=1
    l+=1

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What kind of school do you attend?

Comment: Clear canvas;move dots;draw dots; wait 33ms; repeat.

Comment: good, could you explain the problem more precisely?

Comment: How do I wait for 33ms? I've tried cavas.after, but I haven't been able to successfully use it.

Comment: Is there anything specific I need to clarify? I put down all the instructions given to me about the problem.

Comment: Not the problem you are presented with, but the specific problem you are having.  Having someone on SO do your homework for you is in no ones interest.

Comment: I did state my specific problem. I need to make my code a visual animation. I say that at "The problem with this code is:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the `canvas` does not know what to do for each step of the animation. If you put the code that you use to update the canvas in a function (called, perhaps `redraw()`), call that function in the main course of the program to draw the first image, and include a call like `canvas.after(tim,redraw)` as the last line of the `redraw()` function, that will ensure that the canvas is updated every `tim` milliseconds.

(EDIT)

I'd note also that `randint(-2,2)` generates random selections from the list `[-2,-1,0,1,2]`, not from the list `[-2,2]`, which is what you appear to be hoping for. Also, if you are trying to simulate a four-sided die in which the four sides are: +2x, -2x, +2y, -2y; then computing the random movements in the x and y direction separately won't do this because it would generate movement in both the x and y directions for every point at every time step.

Comment: Thanks! The canvas.after method worked. Your right about the random movement part. Do you have any suggestions on how to go about changing the code so it only moves in one direction every step?

Comment: If you have a look at the `random` module, you'll find an extensive selection of functions. Any of several of them could be used to simulate a four-sided die. Some of the implementation options would need the help of some `if` statements to interpret the result of the die roll in terms of a +x, -x, +y or -y movement.